# rewrite condition in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make partners readable on the website i.e. http://domain.com/partners. but the pinnaclecart doesn't allow it to be readable or accessable on the browser. i created the directory partners so i could write the whole different files from the pinnaclecart.

inside .htaccess: you can see "partners" at the end.

**EDIT II**

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^homepage.html$ index.php
RewriteRule ^home.html$ index.php


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        FileETag None
        <FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
                Header unset Last-Modified
                Header set Expires "Fri, 21 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT"
                Header set Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
        </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine   On
        RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
        RewriteRule     ^((.)?)$        index.php?p=home [L]

        RewriteCond     $1 /var/www
        RewriteRule     ^(.+)$ / [L]

        RewriteCond     $1 !^(\#(.)*|\?(.)*|admin\.php(.)*|ses\/(.)*|ecc\/(.)*|index\.php(.)*|login\.php(.)*|\.htaccess(.)*|images\/(.)*|\.htaccess\.back(.)*|3cc4da-pinnacle_zend_3\.7\.7_sdk\.zip(.)*|dump\.sql(.)*|content\/(.)*|download\.php(.)*|readme\.txt(.)*|in_case_of_install\/(.)*|robots\.txt(.)*|images\.zip(.)*|partners\/(.)*)
        RewriteRule     ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
                SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Why is it not accessable on the browser?

**EDIT**

is there no answer to this for solutions?

Comment: There is only one line in the .htaccess?

Comment: Show more from .htaccess. It will help us. :)

Comment: @akond @Timofey Stolbov, I have posted the entire .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned you may wish to post more of your .htaccess file to help debugging, but I couldn't help but notice that the last part of your regex reads:

```
partners\/(.)
```

This seems odd as it will only match single letter items in that directory. So I am not 100% sure its your problem but I suspect you intended that to read:

```
partners\/(.)*
```

Comment: I have posted the entire .htaccess. Yes you are right about '*' and it is in .htaccess already. still can't access the partners folder inside pinnaclecart folder - can't view it and i got forbidden error.